# Is it possible to use Job Bookmarks with AWS Glue Job on a custom format file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, aws-glue

Please check out this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html 
It says it is possible to enable Job Bookmarks for files in JSON format.
Our format is row-based and looks as follows:

```
[{"a":"a"}, {"b":"b"}]
[{"c":"c"}, {"d":"d"}]
...
```

So each row is a valid JSON but the whole file isn't. 
Is it possible to use Job Bookmark with AWS Glue Job, having our format?

Answer (score 0):

1) Part of your question, re: files that are in S3, "For Amazon S3 input sources, AWS Glue job bookmarks check the last modified time of the objects to verify which objects need to be reprocessed. If your input source data has been modified since your last job run, the files are reprocessed when you run the job again."